# Debug ndk Jni that is a prt of Android application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an application that is partly written in c++ and compiled through the ndk,
that part located on separate jni folder.
My question is: can I debug the c++ code as part of my application?
can I start debug on the sdk and after jump to breakpoint on my jni code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [here is how](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/) curtesy of Martin Hejna

Comment: It's an old post, for some reason my jni folder is in grey with a line on it. and I cant acsses to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book describing that stuff [http://www.amazon.com/Android-Beginners-Guide-Sylvain-Ratabouil/dp/1849691525](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849691525). It helped me but overall C++ debugging in Android is painful, I use printfs instead when possible..